# converting video files to .flv files

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I am having a problem with converting video files to .flv files. I am using ffmpeg.exe tool to achieve this. Here on my local server when I use ffmpeg.exe tool with c# code everything is working good. But when I deploy the same code with ffmpeg tool on to my hosting server, where as .exe files are not allowed to execute, the code is not running. Is there any other way to achieve the same other than redirecting to video conversion sites because I want to save .flv files on my hosting server. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After doing a quick bit of research, there do exist libraries you can use in C# do to FLV encoding, however that could get really pricey...and so could upgrading.

Something you could do...depending on how your current set up is arranged, is have a computer of yours run a CRON job (assuming Linux), or somethign similar, and pull the raw videos uploaded to your site every so often, convert them, and then push them back on to your site. It would mean a bit of wait time for the customer, but it would be a lot chepaer.

Answer (score 0):

Only effective solution is to upgrade hosting to an arrangement where you can run executables such as ffmpeg.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade or use an online converter like [heywatch](http://heywatch.com/page/home)  which has api. But this is double work than upgrading the hosting.